# Open Source Scientific Project - Use Python 2.6 or 2.7?

Tags: python, numpy, version, scipy, optparse

I've seen several other topics on whether to use 2.x or 3.x. However, most of these are at least two years old and do not distinguish between 2.6 and 2.7.

I am rebooting a scientific project that I ultimately may want to release by 2013. I make use of numpy, scipy, and pylab, among standard 2.6+ modules like itertools. Which version, 2.6 or 2.7, would be better for this?

This would also clear up whether or not to use optparse when making my scripts.

Edit: I am working at a university and the workstation I picked up had Python 2.4. Picking between 2.6 and 2.7 determines which distro to upgrade to. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: In a similar [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102999/should-we-use-python-2-6-or-2-7-or-3-x) last year, the sentiment was for 2.7.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think I saw that one in my searching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If everything you need would work with 2.7 I would use it, no point staying with 2.6. Also, `.format()` works a bit nicer (no need to specify positions in the `{}` for the arguments to the formatting directives).

FWIW, I usually use 2.7 or 3.2 and every once in a while I end up porting some code to my Linux box which still runs 2.6.5 and the format() thing is annoying enough :)

2.7 has been around enough to be supported well - and 3.x is hopefully getting there too.

Comment: @Blender Agreed, it took a while for it to grow on me, but I'm glad I made the switch to using it (the majority of the time)

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to distribute this code, your answer depends on your target audience, actually. A recent stint in some private sector research lab showed me that Python 2.5 is still often use.

Another example: EnSight, a commercial package for 3D visualization/manipulation, ships with Python 2.5 (and NumPy 1.3 or 1.4, if I'm not mistaken).

For a personal project, I'd shoot for 2.7. For a larger audience, I'd err towards 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely Python 2.7, unless there is a really compelling reason not to, which usually means the lack of support for a critical dependency. Use [argparse](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/argparse/)

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Enthought's official [distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) uses Python 2.7.  The default Ubuntu python 2.x distribution has been 2.7 for some time.  If you are starting a project from scratch, you should use 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Debian stable for my own projects so naturally I gravitate toward what the distribution uses as the default Python installation.  For Squeeze (current stable), it's 2.6.6 but Wheezy will use 2.7.

Why is this relevant?  Well, as a programmer there are a number of times I wish I had access to new features from more recent versions of Python, but Debian in general is so conservative that I find it's a good metric of covering wider audience who may be running an older OS.

Since Wheezy probably will become stable by the end of the year (or earlier next year), I'll be moving to 2.7 as well.